# Can I restrict user to see my responsive website on their mobile phones?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show my responsive website (using bootstrap) only on desktop, laptop or tablet. Not on mobile phones. So can it be possible for me to do so using HTML, CSS and Bootstrap?

Comment: You can detect if the user is on mobile phone with http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap

```
<div class="visible-xs">
    Sorry, you can't use this site on a mobile.
</div>
<div class="hidden-xs">
    ... my whole site
</div>
```

But this relies on getting the window width, so if a desktop user resizes his window horizontally, you could have a problem.

So, you could instead use media queries and some markup. The CSS

```
<style>
    .minus-mobile {
        display: block;
    }
    .mobile {
        display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
        .minus-mobile {
            display: none;
        }
        .mobile {
            display: block;
        }
    }
</style>
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="mobile">
    Sorry, you can't use this site on a mobile
</div>
<div class="minus-mobile">
    ... my whole site
</div>
```

I've just put in based on width, but you might want to play around with an orientation condition as well.